# SQL Server attach and detach database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error on a different machine which is maintained by IT.

> Could not find row in sysindexes for database ID 40, Object ID 1,
>   Index ID 1. RUN DBCC Checktable on sysindexes.

I am able to attach and detach the database on my laptop.

I tried `DBCC Checktable (SYSINDEXES)` and it gives an error

> Cannot find a table or object with the name Sysindexes.

Any idea on how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Are they same db version on both machines?

Comment: @rs. - Thanks it was different versions and the error was because of compatibility and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Is your table temporary table.If so

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269282/EN-US/

says

Change the non-clustered index that you created on the temporary table to a clustered index.
-or-
Do not use the non-clustered index on a temporary table.

Comment: and how is this related to attaching and detaching databases?